# (Read)File I/O jitter

Tags: c#, file-io

I have an application (C# .Net 3.5 and .Net 2.0) that performs multiple readfile operations. However, the system shows hickups (jitter) every now and then. I have attached VTune profiler and performed a locks&waits analysis, see the first image below.

The locks and waits analysis showed that a "Sync Object: Stream filepath" causes the application to be locked (waiting) on all threads. CPU utilization drops to 0% during this period.

Next, I used SysInternals Process Monitor to log what operation was performed when the hickups occurred. It shows a fileread operation that takes approx. 1 second, but only occasionally (jitter). See the second image.

[image]
single-click large version of image: [here](http://bastijn.nl/zooi/vtune_fileread_jitter.png)

[image: File I/O jitter]
Single-click large version of image: [here](http://www.bastijn.nl/zooi/fileread_jitter.png)

I am puzzled. What could cause this jitter in File I/O? It is a synchroneous read. I have tried to reduce the read buffer from the 32,768b to 4096b, but this did not chance anything. Maybe important to note, the machine used to collect these numbers has an SSD. However, we see similar hickups on machines without SSDs.

Any leads in where to look would be welcome.

Comment: Are you sure is IO, not process? GC collection would fit the pattern. Not sure if VTune can show it, but [WPA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448170.aspx) can show IO actual completion time as opposed to app blocking time.

Comment: I thought the same, I have used an in-house garbarge profiler which did not show apparent leads (no GC2 collections, which are the expensive ones). Yet, I am still not exactly sure if GC can be discarded completely as it is hard for me to cross-link the GC2 collects with the other profiler logs. Thank you for the WPA, let me see if I can reproduce something similar with VTune.

Comment: Does the CPU utilization drop to zero accross the board, or just in the monitored threads? If it's really zero, it probably isn't the GC (it blocks all the managed threads, but it ideally causes 100% CPU utilization during that time). If it's zero except for one thread, it is a bit of a pointer towards GC as the culprit. And you're mistaken, GC0 can be just as much of a slowdown as GC2, that depends on your memory usage patterns.

Comment: The CLR will **not** block a ReadFile() call during a garbage collection.  Such a thread can only block when it returns from a system call.  Clearly taking a second to read 32KB from a disk is completely excessive.  You need to consider an environmental problem, anti-malware first, driver next.

Comment: @Luaan yes I need low latency :). It shows an overall CPU utilization drop to almost 0% (see vtune image, CPU overall). We do not create buffers over and over. Hans Passant & Luaan : Thanks for the input. I will add them as items to the list.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't realize it's the WinAPI ReadFile, not just some ReadFile .NET method you're using. GC has no power there. Comment withdrawn :)

Comment: Just in case: There is no anti virus or any other online monitoring tool on the machine that is not able to quickly scan your file on access?

Comment: After reading hans' comment I have disabled it, and the results were the same. Meanwhile, I have been digging deeper but without much succes. At the end of day I got the WPA setup running so that I will look into tomorrow. Thanks for all the suggestions so far.

Comment: Could we get some resolved symbols for your vtune trace? That would give a better picture about what is happening. Microsoft public symbols can be fetched from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552208(v=vs.85).aspx

Also we need to remember I/O is a single resource, if you can reproduce this problem easily, open up Resource Monitor and watch the disk queue length for the HDD which contains the file being read. There might just be something else doing a bunch of I/O and thus your waiting for that to complete.

Answer (score 2):

This question needs an update. I will post this in the form of an answer as I have solved the issue, yet not in a way that I can say for sure what was the original issue.

I have tried a lot of things to find out what caused the occasional spike in IO read(file) duration. First of all, virusscanners matter, especially McAfee caused some trouble. The comments on the question hinted here already, and @remus rusanu's tip to use WPA/WPR combo showed this as well. WPA/WPR combo pleasantly surprised me and is a valuable tool next to VTune, and ProcMon. The first image shows a spike in McAfee taskmanager just before some long duration flushes and reads start (>1s). The second shows that all information in WPA is nicely linked over all graphs. A nice and strong tool, if searching for that needle in the haystack.

[image]
Quicklink large version: [here](http://www.bastijn.nl/zooi/virus.png).

[image]
Quick larger version: [here](http://www.bastijn.nl/zooi/virus2.png).

Yet, when I uninstalled the virusscan software spikes did still occur. Less frequently, and they were shorter in duration, but still visible in the application. I have tried numerous things to find out what it was. Used VMWare setups so I could completely strip the system and see if other processes might be the issue. In the end, I gave up. I implemented a system to workaround the issue, and this is sufficient for now. Knowing all the actions I took I would say there was another conflicting process. Another option is the linked unmanaged program, which used Mutexes, maybe doing some problematic stuff. I changed the mutex to CriticalSections, but no direct visible results, so I gave up on that route.

To conclude, unfortunately I have no direct answer. Due to time constraints I was forced to work around it, and will probably never know what the root cause for the issue was. I guess that is real life as well..

Thanks for all the tips, I learned some things I will certainly use in the future.